# Windows 7 vpn lose internet connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco

When I connect to Cisco VPN client I lose internet connection.  The option to uncheck default gateway doesn't appear for me. all i could see is the below screen when i click on 'IP V4' advanced settings.[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had ip conflict with vpn server